# perform an asynchronous query in PHP using "Guzzle"

Tags: php, http, guzzle6

make an asynchronous query with PHP using Guzzle and not wait for the result.

- how to retrieve JSON content into another PHP file?

  ```
  <?php
         require '/tools/guzzle-master/vendor/autoload.php';
          use GuzzleHttp\Client;
          use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
          $url = 'https://xxxxxxx/receive.php;
            /*creating a client*/
          $client = new Client();
           /*JSON formatting */
          $param = array(
              'order_id' => 4544,
              'type' => 0,
              'amount' => 1266,
              'fullname' => 'qdxeq',
              'account' => 'dqad',
              'callback_url' => 'http://yuexingy.top/Withdraw/WithdrawCallback.aspx',
              'device_type' => 'dqd',
              'device_id' => 'dafwe',
              'device_ip' => 'dwe',
          );

          $json = json_encode($param);//json encoding
          $data = array('json'=>$json);
          $req = new Request('POST',$url, $data);
          //sending the asynchronous request
          $promise = $client->sendAsync($req,['timeout' => 10])->then(function ($response) { 
          echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
          });
          $promise->wait();
      ?>
  ```

Comment: php is not asynchronous, the script must execute and perform a set of actions in order.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Hi,I retouched the code as below. except that the request is not sent. I would just send the request without waiting for an answer.

Comment: Hi,I retouched the code as below. except that the request is not sent. I would just send the request without waiting for an answer.